# SDcard removal notification, how it is done? Broadcast or Service?

Tags: android, storage, external, sd-card

I need to implement the sd card removal notification which is already present in android, I need to know how it is being done?? Any sample code or tutorial would be of much help.

Answer (score 5):

you need to use Broadcast Receiver for SD Card Removed

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //If SD Card is Removed it will Come Here

           //Intent service = new Intent(context, WordService.class);
    //context.startService(service);
}
}
```

Add Receiver in your Android Manifest File Like Below Code.

```
  <receiver android:name="MyReceiver " >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: is it MEDIA_REMOVED or MEDIA_EJECT?? and should i include any permissions in manifest file???

Comment: `ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT` is broadcast when the user is *about to* remove the SD card (similar to "safe device removal" on Windows); `ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED` is sent once the card has actually been removed. No permissions needed as far as I know.

Comment: @TonythePony Which will first Broadcast in case i have add Both Action in my receiver?.Or Should i need other Broadcast Receiver for Check which Received First .`MEDIA_REMOVED` or `MEDIA_EJECT`.

Comment: `*EJECT` comes before `*REMOVED`, but the user's removal attempt might be aborted.

Comment: If your app uses files on external storage, it should close them when `*EJECT` is broadcast.

Comment: One more thing that if i want to receive both Receiver then i need Two difference Broadcast for `MEDIA_REMOVED` or `MEDIA_EJECT`.

Comment: @Herry i guess not as you can compare the received intent. And this sdcard removal, what if i connect my phone to pc does it count as sdcard removed and whether the intent will get fired for this also??

Comment: No it will not Count as SD Card Remove till You select USB Sd Card Mount in android mobile.it will start in pc as SD card.

Comment: can i have a dialog box inside onReceive() ?

Comment: No you need to Start Activity from your Broadcast Receiver .in this Activity you can start Dialog.you can not direct Create Dialog in OnReceive().`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />`.you can start your Activity as we normally do in other .

Answer (score 1):

The system broadcasts Intents on various events, many of which are about the state changes of the SD card (external media).

So you just need to set up a BroadcastReceiver for the proper Intents. Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) page for reference. You're looking for the ACTION_MEDIA_* Actions.

Comment: does anyone know how to add a new api in android?